Allowing manual sharing to users that are not owners and do not have modify all
we have security wise complex org. That org is used for many things, alongside with CI/CD tool. I have more than 300 users of that tool and about 200 pipelines. In order that user can access pipeline I have to do manual sharing of records on 5 objects. Each of them have between 2 and 10 records. And it is not one time since people are changing projects, new devs are added, removed etc.
I cannot give them view all/modify all since they might mess up someone else project nor they need to see all of that. But - I want to give them option to share/unshare records that have been initially shared with them.
Maybe I am lost but I do not see solution here, unless I create some kind of screen flow/apex sharing that they can initiate. Or create criteria based sharing. But even criteria is not on table as there is no logic how to share and to whom. I would need 50 public groups and still I would need to add/remove users from groups as they do not have access to it.
Any help is welcome.

Flow:
Using Flow for this requirement might lead to scalability issues. Managing governor limits like SOQL (101 queries) and DML (201 operations) can become challenging, especially if the flow needs modification every time record sharing is initiated.
Apex:
So here is the high level design you might need to implement your use case:
From apex we you can use apex managed sharing, to share the record to desired users.

Use Apex to fetch active users and the required fields based on your use case.
Add a button visible only to admins or users with specific permission sets. This button should open a modal upon being clicked.
3.Inside the modal allow selection of:

Users( combobox of list of users coming from apex) and access level(read or edit) and a button (let's say "Allow Access) to authorize users.
Note: We can allow selection of multiple users here.

On click of  "Allow Access" button authorize the users in the UI i.e., the modal.

In apex you need to manage creating, updating and deletion of shares(__share):
ParentId = 'Respective Id',
UserOrGroupId = 'User or group id',
AccessLevel = 'Access Level,
RowCause = 'Manual'


Example:
RecordShare share = new RecordShare();
share.ParentId = 'RespectiveRecordId';
share.UserOrGroupId = 'UserId';
share.AccessLevel = 'Edit'; 
share.RowCause = 'Manual';
insert share;


Grant the above to respective users on click of a button "Allow Access" in the modal which is opened on share button.

But you need to handle the case of updating and deletion users in the modal too.


